# ¿Como puedo obtener un valor GET en una Class Based View?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-class-based-views

Me gustaría saber cual es la forma para usar el GET que obtengo de otra platilla en un `get_queryset`:

```
class CalificacionList(ListView):

    Model = Calificaciones
    template_name = "panel_admin/listar.html"
    def get_queryset(self):
            no_control = request.GET.get()""" En esta parte no se como cachar el valor get que estoy recibiendo"""
            q = Calificaciones.objects.filter(
                Q(alumno__no_control = "no_control")
                ).order_by('grado')
            return q
```

Los modelos que tengo relacionados son los siguientes:

```
class Alumno(models.Model):

    no_control = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    pin = models.IntegerField()
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    apellido_paterno = models.CharField(max_length = 20, null = True, blank=True)
    apellido_materno = models.CharField(max_length = 20, null=True , blank = True)
    nivel_educativo = models.CharField(max_length = 20, null=True , blank = True)
    grado = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    domicilio = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name="alumnos"
        verbose_name_plural="alumnos"

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s %s %s" %(self.no_control,self.nombre, self.apellido_paterno, self.apellido_materno) 


class Materia (models.Model):

    nombreMateria = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique = True)
    clave = models.CharField(max_length=6, unique = True)
    grado = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombreMateria

class Calificaciones (models.Model):

    alumno = models.ForeignKey(Alumno, on_delete = models.CASCADE )
    materia = models.ForeignKey(Materia, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    grado = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    Unidad1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Unidad2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Unidad3 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Unidad4 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Unidad5 = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Calificaciones"
        verbose_name_plural="Calificaciones"

    def unicode(self):
        return self.alumno
```

Y la parte en donde obtengo la PrimaryKey es aquí:

```
from django.urls import path

from sistema.views import *


app_name = 'alumno'  
urlpatterns = [
path('administrador/listar/<int:pk>', CalificacionList.as_view(), name='listar'),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todo lo que pases a través de la URL definida aquí:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('administrador/listar/<int:pk>', CalificacionList.as_view(), name='listar'),
]
```

En este caso para `pk`, lo puedes obtener a través de `self.kwargs` en los métodos de tu clase:

```
class CalificacionList(ListView):

    model = Calificaciones
    template_name = "panel_admin/listar.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
            no_control = self.kwargs.get('pk')
            q = Calificaciones.objects.filter(
                Q(alumno__no_control=no_control)
                ).order_by('grado')
            return q
```

Con eso debería bastar.

Comment: Funciono perfecto gracias